# Show that $(n - 1)2^{n+1} + 2 + (n+1)2^{n+1} = n(2^{n+2})+2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm having a really hard time showing this equality is true, I've tried several ways of going about it and I just can't seem to make it work. Help!

$(n - 1)2^{n+1} + 2 + (n+1)2^{n+1} = n(2^{n+2})+2$

Thanks!

Comment: It is not true for $n=1, 2,3,..$.

Comment: This equality is equivalent to $(3n-2)2^n = 4n2^n$, and it is true only at $n=2$.

Comment: Actually, @tetori, you mean $n = -2$.

Comment: @J.H. Oh, It is my mistake :(

Comment: Thanks guys, I made a mistake in transcribing the problem ::shakes my head::, it's been a loooong day... I fixed it

Comment: $\rm (n-1)2^{n+1}+(n+1)2^{n+1}=(n-1+n+1)2^{n+1}=(2n)2^{n+1}=n2^{n+2}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\begin{align}\color{darkred}{\bf(n - 1)}\color{blue}{\bf 2^{n+1}} + 2 + \color{darkred}{\bf (n+1)}\color{blue}{\bf 2^{n+1}} & = \color{darkred}{\bf(n - 1 + n+1)}\color{blue}{\bf 2^{n+1}} + 2 \\ \\
& = 2n\cdot2^{n+1} +2 \\ \\ 
& = n\cdot 2\cdot 2^{n+1} + 2 \\ \\
& = n\cdot 2^{n+2} + 2 \\ \\
\end{align}$$

Comment: I like just RED, Amy. I feel this color. +1

Answer (score 2):

$$a\cdot 2^{n+1} + b\cdot 2^{n+1} = (a+b)\cdot 2^{n+1}$$

by the distributive law. Now let $a=n-1$ and $b=n+1$. Then $a+b=2n$.

Answer (score 1):

Just let $A=2^n$. Then $2^{n+1}=2\cdot 2^n=2A$ and $2^{n+2}=2^2\cdot 2^n = 4A$. Then your equality reads:
$$2(n - 1)A + 2 + 2(n+1)A = 4nA+2.$$
Let us show that this is indeed true:
$$2(n - 1)A + 2 + 2(n+1)A = 2A(n-1+n+1)+2=2A(2n)+2=4nA+2,$$
as desired.